Swiper 9 Angular Ionic - thumbs carousel stops selecting the main slide when loop is turned on
This is a question to enable me to post an answer I have established after much experimentation in case anyone else hits a similar issue as I have not found it documented so well - any improvement ideas would be great.

I setup a swiper with a main carousel and a thumbs carousel (to select the image in the main one) like the below (in an Angular / Ionic project, with Swiper 9).
This worked great when run in a browser on PC through Ionic.
  <swiper-container style="--swiper-navigation-color: #fff; --swiper-pagination-color: #fff" thumbs-swiper=".my-thumbs" space-between="10" navigation="true" class="mySwiper" #largeSwiper>
    <swiper-slide *ngFor="let image of images">
      <img [src]="image" alt="Slide Image">
    </swiper-slide>
  </swiper-container>

  <swiper-container class="my-thumbs" slides-per-view="3" space-between="10" watch-slides-progress="true" #thumbsSwiper>
    <swiper-slide *ngFor="let image of images>
      <img [src]="image" alt="Slide Image">
    </swiper-slide>
  </swiper-container>

    const swiperEl = this.largeSwiper.nativeElement;
    const thumbsswiperEl = this.thumbsSwiper.nativeElement;

    const options: SwiperOptions = {
      pagination: { clickable: true },
      slidesPerView: 1,
      spaceBetween: 10,
      watchSlidesProgress: true,
      loopedSlides: 4,
      freeMode: true,
    };

    const thumbsOptions: SwiperOptions = {
      pagination: { clickable: true },
      slidesPerView: 2,
      spaceBetween: 10,
      watchSlidesProgress: true,
      loopedSlides: 4,
      loop: true,
      freeMode: true,
    };

    Object.assign(swiperEl, options);
    Object.assign(thumbsswiperEl, thumbsOptions);

I then added in a 'loop' for the thumbs carousel - the change made was to the thumbsOptions by adding the parameter:
      loop: true

Now whilst the thumbs carousel would loop, when I selected a slide from the thumbs carousel it did not change the slide in the main carousel - the core functionality had broken.  When I removed the new entry, functionality resumed (but naturally the tumbs carousel did not loop)
I searched through various artlicles, bugs, and documents most suggesting setting various events e.g.
      on: {
        slideChange: (swiper: any) => {
          this.thumbsSwiper.nativeElement.swiper.activeIndex = swiper.realIndex;
        }
      }

Variations on this theme did not work out well - I also tried setting the SlideChangeTransitionEnd hook.

I think you should just use slideTo method on swiperEl to move it to proper index taken from thumbs.

Similar - it turned out to need slideToLoop() method, which works with the changing index of the looping thumbs.  Thanks for the response!

It turned out the answer was slideToLoop() as a funtion - call this on click of the thumbnail and use the index to set the reference - this is implemented to handle the nature of the loop as opposed to slideTo().
It took a long time to find this nuance, so sharing here.
